# Navisworks Source File Name (LcOaPartitionSourceFilename) property is neither in the properties DB nor in the properties json

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm looking for the "Item > Source File Name" (LcOaPartitionSourceFilename) property of translated Navisworks NWD files.

The NWDs get translated to SVF2, using the default settings.

But I can't find that property back, neither in the SQLite properties DB, nor in the properties json that is returned from the {urn}/metadata/{guid}/properties endpoint.

Is this a bug, or a known limitation, or am I missing a translation setting?

Comment: I'm checking with our engineering team, and will get back A.S.A.P.

Comment: Hi WoWen, both `Source File Name` and `File Name` are removed during translating to  svf/svf2, according to our engineering team. So, could you share the reason why you want this property?

Comment: Hello, we are connecting Navisworks files to an asset register.
The problem with Navisworks is, that it doesn't have persistent item IDs.
See: - https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/navisworks-api/how-to-uniquely-identify-a-model-item/m-p/5761493#M2056
For normal "CAD element" items, we store a concatenation of sourceFileName,sourceCadElementId as identifier.
For "File" items, we used the "Source File Name" as an identifier.
We've now changed that and just use the item "Name". Not ideal, but should be fine for real world projects.

Comment: Thank you, I passed your use case to our engineering team.

Comment: BTW, I wonder if it's ok for you to change it to the name property rather than the name source file name. Will it take lots of efforts to do this change?

Comment: That's what I already did:
> "We've now changed that and just use the item "Name". Not ideal, but should be fine for real world projects."

And no, it wasn't a huge amount of work.

Thanks for your efforts.